# bash suspect just started process

Tags: linux, bash, shell, process, scripting

I have a binary that I start in a bash script and want to print its pid and name.
Ideally I would do:

```
./binary 2>&1 | tee some_text_file &
myBinPid=$(jobs -p)
kill -STOP "${myBinPid}"
myBinName=$(cat "/proc/${myBinPid}/comm")
kill -CONT "${myBinPid}"
echo "process '${myBinName}' has pid: ${myBinPid}"
wait "${myBinPid}
```

The issue here is that this binary is finishing quite fast and sometimes the kill -STOP cmd reports there is no such pid in use.
So, I am thinking of either stopping the bin process right after launching (HOW ?)
or maybe I should be getting the pid/name in some other way (HOW ?).

Edit1: getting the pid does not seem to be the issue though, rather the rest of the commands using that pid. So I gues the question is can I get process name knowing it's pid even if it's terminated (normally or not) ?

Comment: FYI, `myBinPid=$!`. If the process has already completed, though, why would you need its (former) PID?

Comment: @John11 : While chepner is absolutely right, if you want to raise the probability that your background program is still alive, when you want to stop it, put a sleep command in it (and recompile it).

Comment: updated the question a bit + cannot edit binary source code and I do need it's pid even if it terminated normally or not. But the pid might not be a problem here, the proc name might be

Comment: What about `{ cat /proc/$$/comm > sometempfile; ./binary 2>&1 | tee some_text_file; } &` and `myBinName=$(cat sometempfile)`. I don't think it's possible to start a stopped job. But you could stop yourself too I think `{ kill -STOP $$; ./binary 2>&1 | tee some_test_file; } &`. Shouldn't `myBinName` be always `bash`?

Comment: @KamilCuk no binNAme is just some binary, not bash, this is all in some script

Comment: but `./binary 2>&1 | tee some_text_file &` runs bash in the background. I think `/proc/${myBinPid}/comm` will either be always equal to `tee` or to `bash`. In my shell `/usr/bin/sleep 10 | tee /tmp/a & cat /proc/$!/comm` outputs `tee` every time. You could do `./binary 2>&1 > >(tee some_text_file) &`. But still why not just `myBinName=binary`?

Comment: `myBinName=binary` seems like the right approach since any other name the process chooses to set for itself would be a race condition anyways

Comment: What sense does it make the read `comm` from proc, if you know already, which binary you have started?